# Run time exception when debugging locally: FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.resources

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, nuget-package, filenotfoundexception

I got this error:

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'BindingFailure' 
>     Message=Managed Debugging Assistant 'BindingFailure' : 'The assembly with display name 'Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.resources' failed to load in the 'Load' binding context of the AppDomain with ID 3. The cause of the failure was: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.resources, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

I didn't found information about what this is file: Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.resources

This is my packages.cofig file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault" version="3.0.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core" version="3.0.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.WebKey" version="3.0.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" version="5.0.5" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime" version="2.3.18" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure" version="3.3.18" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="MSTest.TestAdapter" version="1.4.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="MSTest.TestFramework" version="1.4.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Selenium.Support" version="3.141.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Selenium.WebDriver" version="3.141.0" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

The references:

```
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>$(PkgMicrosoft_Rest_ClientRuntime)\lib\net452\Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>$(PkgMicrosoft_Rest_ClientRuntime_Azure)\lib\net452\Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

The properties of Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime reference:
[image]

I reinstall all the nugets from begging, but it didn't work.
What should I do?

Comment: It is not an exception.  This warning is not normally enabled, you need to reset your debug settings so it stops nagging you about this non-critical event.  In recent VS versions use Debug > Windows > Exception settings, tick the "Managed Debugging Assistants" box until it turns in a square.  In older versions of VS that starts with Debug > Exceptions.

Comment: I know, I changed the exceptions settings. But when I want to get a secret from a keyvalut, instead of getting the secert, I am getting the exception/warning. I changed the settings to get hidden exceptions that may point to the real problem.

Comment: This warning has nothing whatsoever to do with keyvaluts and secerts, press F5 to keep going.  And consider to ask about the real problem you want to solve, this question gets you nowhere.